Why is the Taylor series of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ equivalent to multiplying $\frac1x$ by the Taylor series for $\sin x$?
I don't understand why in a case like $\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}$ we can multiply the Taylor Series of $\sin{x}$ by $\dfrac{1}{x}$. The Taylor Series involves taking derivatives. Taking the derivative of $\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}$ is very different from taking the derivative of $\sin{x}$, then dividing by $x$. Yet both ways result in the same answer.
I do not understand why they are equivalent.

But we're not taking the derivative of sine when we do that, so that difference doesn't matter

I'm confused. Are we not since Taylor Series at 0 is defined as summation of f^n(0)x^n/n!? To get the Taylor Series, derivatives need to be taken.

Note that if you divide $f^{(n)}(0)x^n / n!$ by $x$, you get $f^{(n)}(0)x^{n-1} / n!$.  Where in this have we found the derivative of $\sin x / x$?  This gives us information about the derivative of $\sin x / x$ at $x=0$, but that's not surprising because the Taylor series has information about all the derivatives of $\sin x$ at $x=0$.  (if we always had to find the derivatives in order to find the Taylor series, it would be significantly less useful)

I suppose I poorly worded what I was trying to say. I meant that we're using all the orders of derivatives to do the expansion. That means we're finding d/dx[sinx/x]*x^0/0! and so forth. I'm asking how that expansion is equivalent to (d/dx[sinx]*x^0/0!)/x and so on.

That means we're finding --- This is one formula for the Taylor series. Technically, the Taylor series of a (sufficiently nice) function is defined as the limit of an infinite series of polynomials in which certain relationships (more specifically, certain approximations) between the function and the polynomials are satisfied. Taylor's Theorem tells us that we can obtain the coefficients of the polynomials by taking certain derivatives of the function (i.e. the "Taylor Theorem" is not the definition of "Taylor series").

"Yet both ways result in the same answer." That's normal. You can solve a problem in two different ways and get the same answer. Something would be wrong if the two different ways gave you incompatible answers. It's the beauty of mathematics that things come together consistently like that.

There are obviously different ways to approach but that's not what I'm asking about. I'm asking about some reasoning or intuition behind why they are.

Let $f(x)$ be a smooth function. $g(x) = (x-x_0)f(x)$. Let's recall the Taylor's theorem:
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n f^{(k)}(x_0)\frac{(x-x_0)^k}{k!}+h_n(x-x_0)(x-x_0)^{n}$$
where $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}h_n(x-x_0) = 0$. Multiply both sides by $(x-x_0) $ gives
$$(x-x_0)f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} f^{(k)}(x_0)\frac{(x-x_0)^{k+1}}{k!}+h_n(x-x_0)(x-x_0)^{n+1}$$
thus
$$g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} f^{(k)}(x_0)\frac{(x-x_0)^{k+1}}{k!}+h_n(x-x_0)(x-x_0)^{n+1}$$
Assume that the Taylor series of $f(x)$ at $x = x_0$ converges i.e. $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}h_n(x-x_0)(x-x_0)^{n} = 0$ and $|x-x_0| \leq 1$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}h_n(x-x_0)(x-x_0)^{n+1} = 0$ and
$$g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f^{(k)}(x_0)\frac{(x-x_0)^{k+1}}{k!}$$
Therefore the Taylor series expansion of $g(x)$ at $x_0$ is equal to the Taylor series expansion of $f(x)$ at $x_0$ multiplied by $(x-x_0)$, for $|x-x_0| \leq 1$
Let $f(x) = \sin(x)/x$ extended to $\mathbb{R}$ and $g(x) = \sin(x)$ then you'll have the corresponding result.

Note that
$$\begin{align*}
g(x) = xf(x) &\qquad & g(0) = 0\cdot f(0) = 0 \\ g'(x) = xf'(x) + f(x) & & g'(0) = 0\cdot f'(0) + f(0) = f(0) \\ g''(x) = xf''(x) + 2f'(x) & & g''(0) = 0\cdot f''(0) + 2f'(0) = 2f'(0) \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ g^{(n)}(x) = xf^{(n)}(x) + nf^{(n-1)}(x) & & g^{(n)}(0) = 0\cdot f^{(n)}(0) + nf^{(n-1)}(0) = nf^{(n-1)}(0) \end{align*}$$
If you set $g(x) = \sin x$, then $f(x) = \sin x / x$, and the above derivation gives the relationship between the Taylor series of $g$ and the Taylor series of $f$.  You can double-check that this is identical to the result you'd find by just dividing the Taylor series of $\sin x$ by $x$.
I want to emphasize, though, that we aren't meaningfully dividing the derivatives of $\sin x$ by $x$.  The terms of the Taylor series already have factors of $x^n$ and their coefficients are functions of $n$ and the $n$th derivative at $0$.  Therefore, multiplying/dividing the Taylor series by $x$ actually shifts the derivatives up or down, accounting for the fact only one term survives in the above derivation, and it's not the $n$th derivative.

There is a general theorem that says any series can be multiplied by a constant:
$$ c \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c\cdot a_k$$
We have the Taylor series for $\sin x$, meaning that we know that for all $x$:
$$ \sin x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k x^k$$
Where $b_0=0$, $b_1 = 1$, $b_2 = 0$, $b_3 = -\frac13$, etc.
So apply the theorem about multiplying a series by a constant, taking $c = \frac{1}{x}$, $a_k = b_kx^k$ for some $x \ne 0$:
$$\frac{1}{x}\sin x = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k x^k =
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}b_k x^k
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_kx^{k-1}$$

I suppose you are thinking about the Taylor expansion about $x=0$, to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(x) / x = 1$. In this case it's useful make use of the big O notation and write:
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \frac{x + O(x^3)}{x} $$
meaning that on the numerator you have $x$ plus something which is of order $x^3$ or higher, while at the denominator you have $x$.
Now, the key realization, and the main reason for using the big O notation here, is noticing that no matter what's actually in $O(x^3)$, your limit is always going to be one.
Try a few values to convince yourself. Suppose you replace $O(x^3)$ with $x^3$: the limit is going to be 1. Suppose you replace $O(x^3)$ with $1000 x^3$: still 1. What about $19000 x^3 + 8 x^5 + x^{100}$? Still 1.
